# Fullscreen Detection Algorithm for lockscreen/screensaver

Tags: xorg, c

I'm working on a cross linux fullscreen detection algorithm, for use in detecting lock screen and screensaver.

This is what I have so far:

1. Check if _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN is supported, if it is then fetch _WM_STATE atoms on window and look for the _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN atom
2. If _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN is NOT supported then it uses `XGetWindowRect` and then compres the width and hegiht (rect[2] and rect[3]) to screen width and height obtained via `WidthOfScreen` and `HeightOfScreen` macros.

The issue with this, is that when my script checks the lockscreen WM_NAME of "nux input window" it is finding that `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` atom is supported but it does not find this atom in the _NET_WM_STATE atoms fetched, the state atoms fetched are:

- 298 _NET_WM_STATE_STICK
- 296 _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR
- 297 _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER
- 315 _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED

We see the fullscreen atom of 291 is not present. But we find that window_rect width and heiht are equal to screen width and height.

How come the full screen atom isn ot showing for "nux input window" which is the lockscreen?